# Grading Students in JS with recursion - Range Error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I was trying to work on this hackerrank problem.

> Every student receives a **grade** in the inclusive range from
> **0-100** to .
>
> Any  less than **38** is a failing grade.
> *Sam is a professor at the university and likes to round each student's  according to these rules:*
>
> If the difference between **grade** the  and the next multiple of
> **5** is less than **3**, round  up to the next multiple of **5**. If the value of **grade** is less than **38**, no rounding occurs as the
> result will still be a failing grade.
>
> Given the initial value of  for each of Sam's  students, write code to
> automate the rounding process.

My code is:

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
  const roundup = y => y + 1;
{
   if ( grades < 38 || grades % 5 === 0) return grades;
   else if ( grades % 5 < 4 && grades % 5 !== 0) return roundup(grades);
}
{
   if (roundup % 5 === 0) return roundup;
   else { gradingStudents(roundup + 1) }
}
}

gradingStudents(38) // -> 39
```

I tried to use `Math.ceil(grades)` inside the variable **roundup** but output didnt change. So, when you invoke the function with a number that is not before a multiple of 5 (e.g. 43) it returns the proceeding number. However, if it is the number before a multiple of 5 it gives a range error. "maximum call stack size reached."

As far as I got, the code doesnt proceed to the second part. Even if it did, I am not sure if it would fetch the current value of the function roundup when dealing with if statements in the second block.

What do I dont get in here?

Also, this is actually meant for an array output but since I am a beginner I am pretty much okay with this one for the start as well :D .

Answer (score 2):

Javascript solution:

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
  return grades.map((grade) => {
    if (grade > 37) {
      const offset = 5 - (grade % 5);
      if (offset < 3) {
        grade += offset;
      }
    }
    return grade;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution calculates the next multiple of `5` no bigger than the grade and uses that value to test whether or not to round up (`next5 - grade < 3`).

We write a simple function to round an individual grade and then for a list of grades use `.map` with that function.

```js
const roundGrade = (grade) => {
  const next5 = 5 * Math.ceil (grade / 5)
  return (grade < 38) ? grade : (next5 - grade < 3) ? next5 : grade
}

const gradingStudents = (grades) =>
  grades .map (roundGrade)

console .log (gradingStudents ([73, 67, 38, 33]))
```

Note that, as with most solutions to this problem, no recursion is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1-Use the `Array.prototypt.map` according to the question logic.

```js
const gradingStudents = (grades) => grades
            .map(n => (n >= 38 && n % 5 >= 3)?(n + ( 5 - ( n % 5 ) )):n )
            
let result = gradingStudents([0,25,38,56,89,77,78,57,58])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think it is too complicated for a beginner to understand. You can add some description, I reckon.

Comment: The rule for those less than 38 is not to remove them, only not to round them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {  //input: 43
var finalGrade; 
if(grade < 38)              
    return grades;
else{
    var gradeDif = grades % 5; //3
    if(gradeDif > 3){
        return grades;
    }
    else {
        return grades + (5 - gradeDif); //Output: 45

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this

```js
function gradingStudents(grades) {
    grades.map((grade,i)=>{        
        if(grade >= 38){                
           let fg = (grade/5).toString().split('.');
            if(fg[1]>5){
                grades[i]=((parseInt(fg[0],10)+1) * 5);
            };     
        }
    });
    return grades;
}

console.log(gradingStudents([73,67,38,33]));
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
    return grades.map(function(grade)  {
        return (grade >= 38 && grade % 5 >= 3) ? grade + 5 - (grade % 5) : grade;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it in python, I will accept it is very basic,

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
for i in range(len(grades)):
        n=grades[i] % 5
        if (5-n<3):
            if((grades[i]+(5-n)>=40)):
              grades[i]=grades[i]+(5-n)
return grades
```